# Does it matter if I set random_state same for RandomForestClassifier() and train_test_split()?

Tags: python, scikit-learn

In sciki learn, `RandomForestClassifier()` and `train_test_split()` both have `random_state` parameter.

Statistically, does it matter if I set them to be the same seed? Will that be wrong? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Nothing will be wrong to set the same seed.